# Create javascript function in codeigniter

Tags: php, javascript

Hi I am trying to create a javascript function that I already have the php methods for.  Once I can send the url/path data it performs the function.

I am trying to send post_id to the php function (which I can do via myurl.com/dashboard/post_id) but I want to do it via javascript.

Here's what I have so far (it's not a lot):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function vote(type,post_id) 
        {
        }
</script>
```

and then:

onclick="vote('up','');"

I want to send post_id (using variable TYPE: )

myurl.com/dashboard/vote/$post_id

Comment: Pass the $post_id from your dashboard controller to the view where the javascript function has been put

Comment: edit and rephrase. the question is not easily understandable as of now.

Comment: I've updated it, also, Dhruv, the problem is I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: @DanielFein is `ajax` an option?

Comment: @DanielFein if i understood your question correctly, the answer should give you an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CLIENT SIDE**(*using jquery*)

---

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#vote').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        post_id = _________ (retrieve the post_id from the target here)
        $.ajax({

            url: 'mysite/controller/method/', /*put your url */
            type: 'POST',
            data: { TYPE: post_id},                
            success: function(data){alert('success')},
            error: function(){alert('request could not be completed')}

        })
    })
})
```

**SERVER SIDE**

---

```
public function getVote(){

            $vote = $_POST['vote'];
            //Do rest of the coding.

    }
```